# XULRunner Application Request Header Information

Tags: http, browser, xulrunner

I've developed a standalone XULRunner app that I'm using as a site-specific browser. The web application it accesses does filtering of browsers to know whether the browser being used is optimal. I'd like to add my XULRunner app to the list of optimal browsers. I figured that to do this, I'll need to know the HTTP header information that accompanies request sent by the XULRunner app. What information in the HTTP header can I use to identify my XULRunner app? Something like the Gecko Engine version, etc. I've been searching around, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application is usually identified by means of the [`User-Agent` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User-agent_identification). You can see it on the client side by means of the [`window.navigator.userAgent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.userAgent), e.g. the header for Firefox 12 on Windows 7 is:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0

The important part here is `Gecko/...` (identifies a Gecko-based browser) and `rv:...` (Gecko version). The `Firefox/12.0` part should be replaced by something like `MyApp/1.2.3` in your case (name and version number of your application).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Palant. I'm try this out, and I'll let you know how it goes. Just a quick one: Anyway of telling the version of XULRunner used?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Palant. `window.navigator.userAgent` returned the user-agent. All I then needed to do is include the agent signature in my optimal browsers list.

Comment: XULRunner version and Gecko version are always the same.